# How to show hint toast above textview in android studio

Tags: android-studio, onclick, android-toast

I am learning android studio and
I wanted to set custom toast above textview .Whenever onclick event happened in textview
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V6Iop.png)  .
and when Longpress event happened then toast show the main Title of textview, above the textview.

how to do this think in android studio ??